# Sidekiq with authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

I am using Sidekiq with Authlogic to avoid unwanted users visit. I followed everything from this [link](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring)
 but its not working as expected. I used below code

```
# lib/admin_constraint.rb
class AdminConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    return false unless request.cookie_jar['user_credentials'].present?
    user = User.find_by_persistence_token(request.cookie_jar['user_credentials'].split(':')[0])
    user && user.admin?
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
require "admin_constraint"
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq', :constraints => AdminConstraint.new
```

If I logged in as Admin user its working properly. If I logged in as normal user or without logging in it shows **Routing Error** when i try to access that page.

```
No route matches [GET] "/sidekiq"
```

I want to clear this error. Someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

I am using rails 3.2.13 and ruby version 2.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following thing, it should work.

```
class AdminConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    return false unless request.cookies['user_credentials'].present?
    user = User.find_by_persistence_token(request.cookies['user_credentials'].split(':')[0])
    user && user.admin?
  end
end
```